# Instagram Api Спонсор публикации

Tags: php, java, веб-программирование, instagram-api

мне необходимо достать спонсора публикации, но не могу никак найти информацию об этом в https://developers.facebook.com/

```
  $query = [
            'fields' => "business_discovery.username($accountName){" . $searchedParam . '{owner,sponsor_id,permalink,comments_count,like_count,media_url,caption,children,media_type,timestamp}}',
            'access_token' => $this->token
        ];
```

то есть вот этот вариант никак не прокатывает, может кто-то сталкивался?